# how to get the file data from a react-bootstrap formcontrol component

Tags: react-bootstrap

I'm using a form control component to pass an image to an API endpoint via an AJAX call. So far, I'm unable to find information on how to actually target the actual file data.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get the file via onChange:

```
<FormControl type="file" onChange={(e) => console.log(e.target.files)}/>
```

where e.target.files is a FileList containing 0 or 1 files.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using TypeScript, and I kept getting the error `Property 'files' does not exist on type 'EventTarget & FormControlElement'.` Including the following types solved the issue:

```js
const [thumbnail, setThumbnail] = useState<FileList | null>(null);
...
<Form.Control type="file" onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => setThumbnail(e.target.files)} />
```